How do i get rid of this i want urgent help

It just shows like this was installing anchor for cli
please help

Downgrade from the latest version of rust to 1.79
rustup install 1.79.0

Set it as the default
rustup override set 1.79.0


you sure this will work

There was a dependecy to time package that broke AVM you can either use rust < 1.80 like Jimii pointed out or install anchor directly like so without the --locked flag:
cargo install --git https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor --tag v0.30.1 anchor-cli
here is the related issue:
https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/3126
